# How can I get the content of the home page?

Tags: templates

I have set my WP site to use a static home page.  I created a file in the root of the theme directory called front-page.php and this template is called correctly.  I cannot seem to display the content of the home page in my template.  I have tried get_the_content, the_content and the post_content object.  What else can I do to get the content of the home page?

```
<?php

get_header();

$page = get_posts( array( 'name' => '' ) ); //here, i have also tried 'home', 'front-page', and 'page-home'
if ( $page )
{
    echo $page[0]->post_content;
}

get_footer(); ?>
```

I have also tried...

```
<?php

get_header();

get_the_content();

get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 7):

alternative to using [the default loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in the front-page.php template:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
  while( have_posts() ) {
  the_post();
    the_content();
  }
}
```

you could try using:

```
if( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
  echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) )->post_content );
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference